# Making a reset menu for my game in unity but don't know how on collision set to a different scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I've just been tinkering with unity and all yesterday I was making a little game. I have a main menu when you start the game, the game itself and a gameover menu when you die that puts you back at the home screen, but I have no clue how to set it when a thing/enemy hits the player, It brings you to the restart menu on collision with it. anyone know any code to help out, I've been trying to find videos but they are not what I need. I need when on collision set scene to GAMEOVER. But don't know how, PLZ help.

Answer (score 0):

So to what I understand you want to make a collision and restart you scene or go to another scene ?

You need to use something like this.

I added 3 possibiities of Scenemanager.LoadScene however you need to use them.

make sure to add the the using UnityEngine.SceneManagement; at the top

```
  using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
    
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
        {
            //if you want to load another scene
            SceneManager.LoadScene("OtherSceneName");
        
            //if you want to load the same scene you are on 
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    
            //if you want to load the same scene you are on 
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1); 
        
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To know if an object with a [Collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) was hit in Unity (e.g. the player) you need to add one of the `OnCollision` functions to your script:

- [`OnCollisionEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) - is called when the object is first hit
- [`OnCollisionStay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionStay.html) - is called every frame while the object is being touched
- [`OnCollisionExit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionExit.html) - is called on the frame the object stops being touched

Then, in the function you can load a different scene using [`SceneManager.LoadScene`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html)